# How should I determine the optimal number of clusters in kmeans in R with large data set?

Tags: r, k-means

I am right now dealing with a large dataset and I have used kmeans and fviz_nbclust in R with wss method to try to determine the optimal clusters in k-means clustering. But as the figure shows, the wss continues to decrease as the number of clusters increases, by quite an amount. I am wondering in this case, what should I do in order to choose the optimal number of clusters.

[image: Figure of WSS]

Comment: You can just google "choose number of k-means clusters" to see tons of opinions. There's no one "right" way to do this. It all depends on what your goals of clustering are. This really isn't a specific programming question that's a good fit for Stack Overflow. There's nothing really R-specific about the question either. If you want statistical advice, you should ask over at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: Ask your stakeholders :)

Comment: Some ideas: silhouette width, gap statistic, bootstrapping, consensus clustering, BIC. There are some good ideas on the topic [here](http://bioconductor.org/books/3.14/OSCA.advanced/clustering-redux.html), although it's a niche field so you may need to ignore some of the specifics.